# Submit package to packagist.org

Tags: 8, composer

I'm trying to submit a module to [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/packages/submit) so that it can be directly installed via `composer`. I've followed the necessary steps and created the [composer.json](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/hover_card/plain/composer.json) as required. Now when I'm trying to submit the module to packagist.org its giving me the following error:

> The vendor is already taken by someone else. You may ask them to add
>   your package and give you maintainership access. If they add you as a
>   maintainer on any package in that vendor namespace, you will then be
>   able to add new packages in that namespace. The packages already in
>   that vendor namespace can be found at drupal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put your Drupal modules on packagist.org. Drupal modules are available on packages.drupal.org, where the module will be automatically exposed if you add it on Drupal.org.

it is explained here:
[Using packages.drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/2822344).